# Unable to call an action from effect

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Am new in angular and ngrx store concept(ngrx and angular version is 13).

am trying to call an action form my `createEffect` method in effects.ts file

`createEffect` method look like this

```
loadData$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType('[Data] Load data'),
      mergeMap(() => this.myService.getDataApi()
        .pipe(
          map((data: Data[]) => ({      
            type: '[Data] Load Success',
            payload:  { data},
            selectedData:data[0],

            return setData(selectedData),
            }
          )),
          catchError((error: any) => of({
            type: '[Data] Load Failure',
            payload:  { error },
            }
          ))
        ))
    )
  );
```

Here am calling an API called `getDataApi`. Once i received the data from back end,setting payod and type.Finally am calling `setData`and pass the fist value from response.

**SetData action**

```
export const setData = createAction(
    '[Data] Set Selected',
      props<{  selectedData: Data}>(),
  );
```

**error**

[image]

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's up with your code? This is a wrong part obviously:

```
map((data: Data[]) => ({      
            type: '[Data] Load Success',
            payload:  { data},
            selectedData:data[0],

            return setData(selectedData),
            }
          )),
```

Change with:

```
switchMap((data: Data[]) => setData({ selectedData: data[0] })),
```